# LibGDX - given an arraylist of moving circles, how can i check for collision between them?

Tags: libgdx, sprite, collision, geometry, detection

So I have 3 classes, MyGdxGame, Ball and DetectCollision. MyGdxGame initialises 4 instances of **Ball** (different colours and speed/direction, all bounce off the sides of the screen) and stores them as an arraylist.

This arraylist is passed through the constructor of DetectCollision:

```
public class DetectCollisions {
ArrayList<Ball> ball;

public DetectCollisions(ArrayList<Ball> ball) {
    this.ball = ball;
    start();
}
public void start() {
for(int i=0; i<ball.size();i++) {
    ...
}
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to where I should go with this? I just want to detect every time a ball collides with another (and eventually I'll have it print the number of collisions).

Any help highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to add a lot of objects to the arraylist, use a 2D physics engine to do all the work for you. If you want to continue implementing your own functions, the very basic method to do is to implement a nested loop over the list to check every possible pair in the arraylist. The complexity is O(n^2)

```
for(int i=0; i<ball.size();i++) {  
    for(int j=i+1; j<ball.size();j++) {
        check(ball.get(i), ball.get(j));
    }
}
```

The method named **check** checks if given two circles collide or not. Checking two circles' collision is very easy. If the distance between the central points of the circles is smaller than the sum of the radiuses of the circles, then they collide. [Check this page](http://cgp.wikidot.com/circle-to-circle-collision-detection) for further info about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to accomplish if you let each `Ball` have bounds of type `Circle`.

You can make a circle as follows: `Circle ballBounds = new Circle(float x, float y, float radius)` This circle can act as the bounds of each ball ultimately allowing you to check if they collide using the `Intersector` class.

Having each `Ball`'s boundary we can easily loop through the `ArrayList<Ball>` and check how many collide. For example:

```
ArrayList<Ball> ball = new ArrayList<Ball>(); // You need to add Balls to this ArrayList

Intersector intersector = new Intersector();

int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < ball.size()-2; i++){
   if(intersecor.overlaps(ball.get(i), ball.get(i+1)){
       counter++;
   }
   i++;
}
```